# Release of resources in SimPy in a different function to where it was requested

Tags: python, simulation, simpy

In a simulation I would like to able to request a resource in one function before calling another function in which the resource is released.  When I use the method shown below it doesn’t work and I get an error.
Thanks in advance.

(in function 1):

```
req = resource.request()
yield req

yield.env.process(function2( ))
```

(in function 2):

```
resource.release(req)
```

Is this possible? Let me know what else if any other information is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From you’re example it’s not clear why it would not work. The simulation below works as expected:

```
import simpy


def func1(name, env, res):
    req = res.request()
    yield req
    print(name, 'got resource at', env.now)
    yield env.process(func2(name, env, res, req))
    print(name, 'done')


def func2(name, env, res, req):
    yield env.timeout(1)
    yield res.release(req)
    print(name, 'released at', env.now)


env = simpy.Environment()
res = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=1)
env.process(func1('A', env, res))
env.process(func1('B', env, res))
env.run()
```

The output:

```
A got resource at 0
A released at 1
A done
B got resource at 1
B released at 2
B done
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This works perfectly I just wasn't passing the request to the next function correctly! Stupid now I see it.
    i.e def func2(name, env, res): not i.e def func2(name, env, res, req):